# How to combine external Vue component with the exisiting Vue on the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Im working on a CMS, where the CMS ships with Vue2.x installed and a few inbuilt Vue components, Im building custom Vue Components and including them to the page, what i wanted to do is I want to mount my components with the already running vue root node.

for ex : `<div id="app"></div>` is the root node that all Vue components run, but how can i mount the external component to the same id.

This is the setup :

```
<script src="vue2x-lib"></script>
<script src="my-vue-components"></script>
```

Comment: You can't mount multiple apps to the same id. You need to register "external" components with the same `Vue` and render them as usual components in the app. Consider explaining your case in details if you have problem with that

Comment: @EstusFlask I think that's what I'm looking at, I want to render the external component as usual. Is there a way that I can get the vue object from window and extend my component? or any other approach should be also fine.

Comment: You need to use Vue CDN in all apps which will be available as window.Vue. Can't say more specifically without details.